# Mobile Reports (SQL Server 2016) - MDX - Change Parameter Dimension in query

Tags: sql-server, mdx

After working with Datazen, I'm currently starting to work with SQL Server 2016.
Some information:
-Dashboards created using MDX queries (so, reading from OLAP cubes).
-SQL server 2016 comes with Report Builder that has the parameters pre-defined (parameter name, dimension, hierarchy).

Datazen/mobile Report uses a timeline  navigation that is created using dates (yyyy-mm-dd format). 
However, since I want the queries to go quick, I receive 2 dates (from day_X to day_Y) and try to perform string manipulation to get month information (for example 201602), another hierarchy, as I was doing in Datazen

Something like:

```
with 
set [Mydates] as STRTOSET("[Tempo].[Tempo].[Month].&["+ CStr(year(cdate('{{ @data1 }}'))) + CStr(format(cdate('{{ @data1 }}'),'MM')) +"]: [Tempo].[Tempo].[Month].&[" + CStr(year(cdate('{{ @data2 }}'))) + CStr(format(cdate('{{ @data2 }}'),'MM')) + "]")
```

In report builder, one must define the receiving parameter dimension, hierarchy and default value.

I have tried the options in the image attached and my feeling is that this is not so easy because probably mobile reporenter image description herets is sending the full unique name and not just the value.

Any ideas?[Check my query here, only works if i place the date as '2016-01-01' not the parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhWF.jpg)

Thanks in advance,
Marta Oliveira